# Invalid conversion error? How do i overcome this error?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I wanted to initialize 5 objects in the array with their positions (0,1,2,3,4). Is this just a syntax error? I feel like I am not properly using the pointers. Please help! Before anyone flags it as a duplicate, I am aware it is similar to a couple other questions but none of their solutions seem to work for me. Unless I'm doing it wrong, which I'll admit is possible, but that's why I'm here.

The output:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CuteRobot{
private:
    int position; //x-axis position
    
public:
    CuteRobot(){};
    
    CuteRobot(int p){ //initialize default position
    position = p;
}

    void getPosition(){ //getter
    cout << "position: "<< position;
}

    CuteRobot& move(int steps){ //Positive number for forward motion, negative number for backward motion.  
                                //Ideally, implement function chaining here, CuteRobot&  move(int steps);  
    if(steps >=1){
        position = position + steps;
    } else {
        position = position - steps;
    }
    return *this;
}

    void meet(CuteRobot* cr){ //The function takes a pointer parameter, calculates the steps value when the cr object meets this objectect, 
                              // assuming this object stands still, and use move() function to bring cr object to this object position.
        int steps = (this->position) - (cr->position);
        cr->move(steps);
    }
};

int main()
{
    CuteRobot* cr[5] ={0,1,2,3,4}; // array of five CuteRobot objects.
    
    for(int i =1; i < 5; i++){ //loop through the array and use meet() method to bring every robots to zero position 
                                //(where the first robot stands)?
        cr[i]->meet(cr[0]);
        cr[i]->getPosition();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay so if i change `CuteRobot* cr[5] ={0,1,2,3,4};` to                                       `CuteRobot* cr{ new CuteRobot[5]{0,1,2,3,4}};` I no longer get the **invalid conversion error** but i do get  a **error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘CuteRobot’** for `cr[i]->meet(cr[0]);` and `cr[i]->getPosition();`

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean an array of them (not a pointer to one):

```
CuteRobot cr[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
```

Then later use object rather than pointer notation:

```
 cr[i].meet(cr);
 ...
```

Comment: but then I get a new error  **error: no matching function for call to ‘CuteRobot::meet(CuteRobot&)’   cr[i].meet(cr[0]);
                                                                     ^**

Comment: Updated.  cr[0] is an object but you want the address.  I.e. &cr[0] or just cr.